# Python Array Copying

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, copy

I'm trying to figure out how to copy an array output into a new array for multiple iterations.  The scenario is to run a function in a for loop with varying inputs then overlay the results on a single plot for comparison.  Currently I have it running where I get three arrays from the for loop, but this results in three independent plots.

My coding is not very solid so some guidance would be appreciated.  I was reading up on the list copy function but have not been able to get it to do what I want.

```
for z,wn in mylist:
    G1 = y_numeric(z,wn)
    #np.array(output[i,:])=G1.copy()
    #plt.figure()
    #plt.plot(t,G1[:])
    #print(G1)
    #print(output)
```

Comment: append all arrays in for loop in a list as below:
list=[]
for loop:
  list.append(arr)
then use np.array(list) or simply fetch each array using list indexing like list[0],list[1],etc for plotting.

Comment: take the plt.figure outside the loop, as a result, plots will be plotted on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user158430, Here is a simple example of a working code that might help you navigate through your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#creating empty list to append all y variables
all_y = []

#creating random variables 
x,y1,y2,y3=np.arange(0,50,1),np.arange(50,100,1),np.arange(100,150,1),np.arange(150,200,1)

#appending only y variables into the created empty list
all_y.extend((y1,y2,y3))

#looping to plot on one single figure
for i in  (all_y):
    plt.plot(x,i)
plt.figure() #this code is kept outside the for loop if desired to print all the plots in one figure, if wanted the plots to be separated then indent it to match the plt.plot (i.e., put it in the loop)
```

This is what you should get:

[image]

Comment: I have it working with plt.figure() outside of the loop as you suggested.  If I want to plot each data set, which is four columns of 100 values, I get 100 plots.  I tried a few combinations such as `plt.plot(t,G1[:,i])` but get an error "arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type."

Comment: @user158430, good to hear that it worked! as for the error you're getting, would it be possible to add in a reproducible example so that we can better assist you?

Comment: Sure.  THis is the most recent example I'm working on, just with different variable names.  The array step_list is 100 x 4 array.  I read up on the .astype(int) syntax but that didn't seem to make a difference or I'm using it incorrectly.

`for i in (step_list):
    plt.plot(t,step_list[:,i])
    plt.title('Step Response')
    plt.xlabel('Time (sec.)')
    plt.ylabel('Data')
    plt.figure()`